# GTM Custom Variable from Console CSS Selector

Tags: variables, google-tag-manager

I am working on trying to pull in Order ID from a purchase event for a client. At the moment I have the CSS Selector as follows

```
document.querySelector(".woocommerce-order-overview__order")?.innerText?.substring(14)
```

How do I take this from the console and write it properly in GTM for a Custom Variable so that the order ID number will populate within a conversion pixel?

This is not for a trigger. this is specifically for a custom variable.

Have not tried anything yet as I have not found forum posts relating to this.

Comment: Have you tried adding this in a javascript variable and seeing what the output is? There might be a lot of trash data that comes through since you are digging into substrings and pages might not have that element on screen.